# Finding the cofficient of a generating function.

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

What is the cofficient of $n^n$ in the generating function $(\log(1-x))^2$?
First i took the taylor coulmn of $\log(1-x)$ and multiple it with itself.then i used the coushi formula.
I got that the cofficient is $\sum_{j=0}{n}\frac{1}{(j+1)^2}$ , but im not sure that it is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is $\sum_{\{j,k \geq 1, j+k=n\}} \frac 1 {jk}$ or $ \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1} \frac 1 {j(n-j)}$.

Note: when you multiply two power series you should use different symbols for the summation indices.

Comment: Ahh ,how can i got that?

Comment: See the note I added to my answer. @Almaa

Comment: Got it! Thanks , i would ask that after multiplying the two coulmns we get $\sum_{n>=2}$.. in the cofficient (the 2nd one which you wrote)?